# post запрос в android-приложении

Tags: java, android, spring

В android-приложении надо сделать post-запрос на сервер.

Кусок кода из приложения сервера

`@RequestMapping(value = "/passwordRecovery", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public BackendData passwordRecovery(HttpServletRequest request,
    @RequestParam(value = "email", required = false) String email) {...
  }`

Приложение android:

```
public interface APIService {

@GET("mobile")
Call<String> getIdUser(@QueryMap Map<String, String> map);

@GET("mobile")
Call<List<CameraSmallDTO>> getCamList(@QueryMap Map<String, String> map);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("http://192.168.1.243:8080/backend/passwordRecovery")
Call<BackendData> passwordRecovery(@Field("email") String email);
```

}

```
public class APIServiceImpl {
public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.243/";
private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                                            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create());

public static <S> S createService (Class<S> serviceClass){
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
private APIServiceImpl (){}
```

}

```
public void passRecovery(View view){

    APIService apiService = APIServiceImpl.createService(APIService.class);
    Call<BackendData> call = apiService.passwordRecovery(loginEditText.getText().toString());

    try {
        backendData = new PassRec().execute(call).get();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Logger.printStackTrace(e);
    }

    if (backendData.isSuccess()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вам выслано письмо на почту", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

private class PassRec extends AsyncTask<Call, Void, BackendData> {
    @Override
    protected BackendData doInBackground(Call... params) {
        try {
            Call<BackendData> call = params[0];
            Response<BackendData> response = call.execute();
            return response.body();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.printStackTrace(e);
            return BackendData.error("error");
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге во время запроса приходит строчка:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden, url=http://192.168.1.243:8080/backend/passwordRecovery}
```

В конфиге спринга на сервере csrf включен, отключать его не хочется, как победить этот токен?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то здесь неавторизированный юзер пытается отправить POST запрос. То на конкретный запрос выключи CSRF:

```
http
 .csrf()
     .ignoringAntMatchers("/passwordRecovery/**")
     .and()
 ...
```